# Isolate the initial quantity of articles on create and update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I create an article I set a quantity.

Each time an article is sold, its quantity is decreased by a method.
I need to keep my initial stock, the number of sales and the remaining stock...

So my question is:

How can I keep the initial quantity, and the quantity I could add on update?

```
# article.rb
before_create :quantity_on_create
before_update :quantity_on_update

def quantity_on_create
  self.quantity
end

def quantity_on_update
    quantity_on_create += self.quantity
end
```

`quantity_on_create` remains nil ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could consider an additional attribute for quantity_stock

```
# article.rb
before_create :quantity_on_create
before_update :quantity_on_update

def quantity_on_create
  self.quantity_stock = self.quantity = 10 # initial value
end

def quantity_on_update
    if self.quantity > 0
      self.quantity -= 1
    else
      errors.add(:base, 'out of stock')
      throw(:abort)
    end
end
```